# Bootstrap 3 - Grid not working with fixed header?

Tags: layout, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3, fixed

I noticed a weird issue:

The bootstrap3-grid fails with my fixed header having a `class="row"`.

Any idea how to fix this?

**Here is a basic example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/EPQqx/5/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after playing around a little (if anyone has the same problem):

```
#header{
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The trick is to add bootstrap-container insíde your fixed div like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
         [content goes here]
    </div>
</div>
```